# How to use list.remove or del to remove rows from a CSV your iterate through using a slice?

Tags: python, csv

Hey everyone how would I use list.remove or del to remove a slice I used to iterate through a list? I have tried multiple combinations and keep getting errors either because the iteration is not a list or because I must provide an integer.

```
import csv
import sys
from itertools import islice

sourcef = sys.argv[1]  
destf = sys.argv[2]  
linestart = int(sys.argv[3])   
lineend = int(sys.argv[4])  

with open (sourcef, 'rb') as file1, open (destf, 'wb') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    writer = csv.writer(file2)
    row = list(reader)
    for i in [slice(reader, linestart, lineend)]:
    #for i in islice(reader, linestart, lineend): 
        row.remove(i)
        print row
```

Comment: Why not just not output rows you don't want to keep?

Comment: @Ignacio, I tried that but it doesn't remove those fields from my original file.

Comment: @DevinSt.Clair to remove from original file, you can write back to it from your modified list. _or_ you can write line by line to another file, and when done, move the file back to the original one (emulating in-place, like `sed` does). That wouldn't take that much memory if the file is big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has little to do with `csv`. Any `list` can be modified to remove adjacent elements using *slice assignment*.

```
>>> row = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> row[slice(2,4)] = []
>>> row
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

note that I've used `slice` but in that case

```
>>> row[2:4] = []
```

is the same. The main interest of the `slice` object is that you can pass it as a parameter/use like a variable.

In your case

```
row[linestart:lineend] = []
```

does the trick

In your case, if the csv file is very large, it could be an issue to fully load it. You could use `enumerate` to filter rows out:

```
reader = csv.reader(file1)
writer = csv.writer(file2)
for i,row in enumerate(reader):
    if linestart <= i < lineend:
       continue  # skip this range
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more verbose @Jean? I understand slicing the way you and @AJ mentioned, but don't understand what I'm doing after that. In my beginner view those just seems to recreate the issue for me, I need to take whatever the output of iterating or in this case a list and remove the range of fields from a csv.

Comment: I don't see your problem. After `row[linestart:lineend] = []` `row` contains all the rows but the ones between those indexes. That seems to answer your question

Comment: Ah! Gotcha, thanks. So now I just need to get the list to output back into CSV form. The whole idea is I want to to parse through a CSV, remove the range of rows I want, then output to a new file. It seemed to me that working with lists was the easier method to achieve this.

Comment: @DevinSt.Clair and it is. However you could use `enumerate` on the rows to filter out some ranges. See my edit.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed and that helped me learn something too. I tend to over think things and the logic gets out of hand. That was so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify your list as you are iterating over it.  That way lies madness.  Print your row as you iterator over it, and then delete the rows at the end.

```
rows = list(reader)
for row in rows[linestart:lineend]:
    print row
rows[linestart:lineend] = []
```

Comment: Hey @AJNeufeld, I'm still new to programming and Python. I understand what printing is for the most, but how does printing what is iterated going to help. Also how would I use that new list you have there are the bottom to del? I tried adding del row[linestart:lineend] after that and it doesn't do anything, surprisingly it still runs without error.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, you had a print statement in your iteration loop - I thought you wanted to print the data as you were removing it.  `rows[linestart:lineend] = []` is the deletion of the rows from `linestart` to `lineend`; you don't need to delete it twice.  Alternately you could use `del rows[linestart:lineend]` instead.  They are equivalent.